# Flash Player POST form submission to Google Drive #2048 Error

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, google-drive-api

So I have project in which I have a Google Drive spreadsheet with a linked form. An ActionScript 3 function is then filling in this data and submitting it. This is working fine... until I open the SWF in debug mode or outside of Flash Professional. I get a 2048 error about the security.

I've done some researching and it's all about accessing it and crossdomain.xml and all that. I didn't really understand it that much, although I understand roughly what the error is. Unfortunately I have not seen a solution to help me out yet.

The SWF and a basic HTML page will be hosted on a Google Sites page if that makes any difference.

So my question is how is the best way to go about this from here? Some form of crossdomain code? Some more AS3? Do I need to host a domain myself? (I'd rather not do this as I know practically no PHP nor much about any web server like MySQL or whatever.)

Comment: Load crossdomain.xml file withing Google. Check out their manual how to do so.

Comment: So, what I just upload a crossdomain.xml file into the same folder that the form/spreadsheet is in? Where am I looking for the manual?

Comment: Nope, you have to upload it in the ROOT folder of the server. If you have no access to this folder you have to write proxy on your own server.

Comment: If it's Google Drive I guess I'll have to make a proxy then. I don't suppose you could recommend a good tutorial? I have no clue about PHP.

Comment: Just read how Google Drive deals with crossdomain. I'm sure it's written somewhere.